# Intrinsic / Bytecode Annotations Security

Tags: bytecode, language-design, intrinsics, jvm-languages

I am currently making a JVM-based programming language. Instead of having operators, I chose to allow symbols as method names and create compiler reference classes for primitive data types. These are annotated with so-called @Intrinsic annotations that take Bytecode instructions as their parameters. Instead of an INVOKE instruction, the compiler uses these to generate the Bytecode at every call.

I am now wondering whether or not this (public) annotation can be used to do anything malicious on the JVM, and if it should be restricted by the compiler, for example by static analysis.

(The language itself also supports Bytecode Expressions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JVM will verify the bytecode before use and the bytecode’s history is irrelevant to this process. In the end, if there is a certain invalid, possibly malicious, bytecode pattern that the verifier doesn’t recognize, its danger doesn’t depend on whether this byte code pattern was created using your compiler and annotations or created by hand.

That’s the reason for the verification concept in the first place. The JVM doesn’t assume that compilers are always error-free.

However, it’s still a good idea to let the compiler perform plausibility checks, static analysis or even perform its own verification of the created byte code. It’s not about security, as said, if a JVM’s security would rely on your compiler doing everything right it would be broken anyway. But it’s about usability, most users like to get an immediate response on errors without the need to actually *run* the code to learn that it’s invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Generally if you can execute code of your choice on the JVM, you can already do everything malicious. The JVM is very hard to sandbox correctly.

The real question is what your threat model is. Normally if you run a compiled executable on your computer, it's assumed to be able to do anything you can do as the current user. Even the JVM follows this model on desktops. (There's also the Java browser plugin which attempts to enforce a Java level sandbox on applets loaded from the web, unfortunately with little success)